What does the admission controller (or webhook controller) `CONNECT` operation entail?
What does the admission controller (or webhook controller) CONNECT operation actually mean? Where is that documented?
// Operation is the type of resource operation being checked for admission control
type Operation string

// Operation constants
const (
    Create  Operation = "CREATE"
    Update  Operation = "UPDATE"
    Delete  Operation = "DELETE"
    Connect Operation = "CONNECT"
)

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/f79c00e8ff43b80a7fb294341027428f01e9f036/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/admission/interfaces.go#L154

I tried to find something about CONNECT too, there is not too much info about it.
The CONNECT operation occurs when a user/process performs a kubectl exec command against a Pod.
You can read a little bit more about it here

Thanks, this helps! I was wondering whether there's a way that a Mutating Webhook can mutate resources that were created before the webhook was installed, and I wondered if either 1) when webhook is deployed, it's submitted every existing resource as if it was CREATEd, the way kubebuilder controllers are setup, or 2) CONNECT has something to do with it. Turns out neither is true. Existing resources won't be processed, unless there's UPDATE to them from something external and my Webhook watches for updates.
